# mongoose $in array with multiple instances

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of `postIds` which can have same `postId` multiple times. Now I have to update each post, and update query has to be fired as many times as the number of times it is present in the `postIds` array.I am using a code like following:

```
models.Post.update({_id:{$in:postIds}}, 
                   {$inc : {'meta.comments' : -1}}, 
                   {multi:true}, function(err, doc){
                     if(err) {
                           console.log(err);
                     }
                   next();
  });
```

This updates the post , but only once.

To be more clear lets say if my postIds array is `[1,2,3,1,2,4,1,1,4]`.  My intention is `postId = 1` to be updated `4`times instead on just once which is happening right now with my code. How can I do this?

PS: iterating the postIds and firing update each time is not the ideal solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that if we consider the core library MongoDB, it is spreading the values in the array into an OR translation. For example, for your array it will be:

```
1 or 2 or 3 or 1 ...
```

Which simply means that each case will happen only once. At this moment, there is no detailed bulk operation for an array, and only available ones are really general due to complexity of doing operations on the arrays.

Of course, you're looking for a consistent method of updating with the lowest number of commands to be sent to the DB. Unfortunately, at this moment, you should try to devise your own lines of code for it, instead of looking inside mongoose.

Well, possibly you can reduce the calls by doing as follows:

```
1- call for [1,2,3,4] using -1 in $inc
2- call for [1,2,4] using -1 in $inc
3- call for [1] using -2 in $inc
```

or

```
1- call for [3] using -1 in $inc
2- call for [1,2,4] using -2 in $inc
3- call for [1] using -4 in $inc
```

Comment: Yup I think that is what i will end up doing because I think it makes more sense to fire the update operation once instead of multiple times. Though I feel mongoose could have handled this as well by introducing an option, which would check the number of times same document has to be updated and then update it in one shot. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code:

```
  models.Post.find({_id:{$in:postIds}}, function(err, elements){
    elements.forEach(function(value){
            value['postIds'].forEach(function(postId){
                if(postId === 1){
                    value['meta.comments'].$inc();
                    } 
                });
            value.save();
        })
  });
```

You can read this doc: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: Similar solution wont solve the problem as well, if there are multiple instances of  postId, and you do find(), the 'elements' in the callback will still have that post only once and hence the meta.comments will be incremented only once for that postId

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) it is as simple as

```
{_id: {$in: _.uniq(postIds)}
```

If not, you can use something like this

```
postIds.filter( (value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index );
```

Comment: Thats not the problem. I dont want unique posts. I rather want it to have multiple instances and update them as many times